# Is there any way to get input from a Scanner without declaring it?

Tags: java

Usually you would declare an input Scanner with `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);`

Is there any way to use a method in the Scanner such as `nextInt()` or `nextLine()` without making an object of the class?

Comment: No. Why would you need that anyway?

Comment: @tevemadar

If I need only one type of input, I'd rather just import that than the entire class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a utility class, create static methods in that utility class and use a `import static` for methods in the utility class. Static method import allows you to use methods from a class without having to explicitly use the class. See the reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_import).

File `TestApp.java`

```
package com.example;

import static com.example.utils.ConsoleReader.nextInt;
// Or use "import static com.example.utils.ConsoleReader.*;" if you want to import every static methods in class "ConsoleReader"

public class TestApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter the number the number");
        // The following line calls the method of the class "ConsoleReader" without having to reference it.
        int input = nextInt();
        System.out.println("You have entered " + input);
    }

}
```

File `ConsoleReader.java`

```
package com.example.utils;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConsoleReader{
    private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public static int nextInt() {
        return scan.nextInt();
    }

    public static String nextLine() {
        return scan.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a static class which returns the desired variable type.

For example, if you wanted to create your own class for reading the next integer:

```
public static int nextInt(){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    return scanner.nextInt();
}
```

However in reality you still have to declare it.

Then you can simply put `nextInt()` in your code to get the next Integer.